# TeXworks won't open *.cls extensions

Tags: installing, miktex

I've always used MikTeX as the main LaTeX base to compile/write my `*.tex/*.sty/*.cls` files, so I downloaded the specific version 2.9.4521-x64 on my first computer (running Windows 7 Professional); and then the file extensions mentioned above were correctly recognized by the OS, as it can be seen inside a generic folder:

> [image]

There is a difference regarding the file type (`tipo=type`) `LaTeX Class` and `LaTeX Style` that recognizes automatically the derived extensions; and so on my first machine I've had no problems at all.

The problem rised when bought a new computer, same OS, and installed the *same version* of MikTeX; then when I looked back on the same folder the file extension for class was no more recognized correctly by Windows:

> [image]

Here the file type that describes a class file is recognized as `CLS file`, and not `LaTeX Class`, because I had to *manually* connect the program that will be able to read the extension, as it can be seen by the different icon appeared in the aforementioned image.

I know it may seem as a not-so-dramatic issue, but *I don't know what is causing it*, and since there is an image proof surely something must have happened.

---

**EDIT:**
As karlkoeller suggested, removing the current TeXworks version from the MikTeX distribution and installing a brand new one generates this output:

[image]

So it looks like I'm back on where I started.

Comment: Note that it is TeXworks that is responsible of these changes, not MiKTeX itself.

Comment: @karlkoeller That is quite problematic, because I couldn't find any documentation that tells exactly how to separate TeXworks from the MikTeX distribution. If I could obtain this info, I'll surely uninstall and replace it with the 0.45 version.

Comment: In "MiKTeX Package Manager" remove "miktex-texworks-bin-2.9". This should eliminate TeXworks from MiKTeX installation.

Comment: @karlkoeller I tried, but the result wasn't too satisfying... (see edit.)

Comment: @karlkoeller Maybe inside the `texworks-config` will be something useful to do. Otherwise, apart from installing antother IDE, what are my possibilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you can do.

I'm assuming that you've installed MiKTeX 64-bit and your installation directory is `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`.

Before proceeding, be sure that the file `miktex-texworks.exe` exists in the folder `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`.

Create a file `additions.reg` with the following contents (adjust it with the right directories if the above assumptions are not right):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bib]
@="MiKTeX.bib.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cls]
@="MiKTeX.cls.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dtx]
@="MiKTeX.dtx.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ltx]
@="MiKTeX.ltx.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sty]
@="MiKTeX.sty.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tex]
@="MiKTeX.tex.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.bib.2.9]
@="BibTeX Database"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.bib.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.bib.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.bib.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.bib.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.cls.2.9]
@="LaTeX Class"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.cls.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.cls.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.cls.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.cls.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dtx.2.9]
@="LaTeX Macros"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dtx.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dtx.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dtx.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dtx.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.ltx.2.9]
@="LaTeX Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.ltx.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.ltx.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.ltx.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.ltx.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.sty.2.9]
@="LaTeX Style"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.sty.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.sty.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.sty.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.sty.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.tex.2.9]
@="TeX Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.tex.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.tex.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.tex.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.tex.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\miktex-texworks.exe\" \"%1\""
```

At this point, the only thing you have to do is to double-click this file so to add this information into the Windows registry. If you are not able to see the icons, restart Windows.

Comment: One more thing. After double-clicking on `additions.reg`, what should I do with the file afterwards? Do I have to delete it or keep it? (by induction I'd say the first but I'm not sure).

Comment: After the info has been incorporated in the Windows registry you can delete it.

Comment: After doing everything the OS continues to recognize only `CLS file`, I'm starting to think that on its own has decided to get on my nerves now...

Comment: Do you have admin rights?

Comment: At a first glance I'd say yes but I'm 99.99% sure. Is there a way to confirm this (I know it may be not related to TeX, but it'd help me to understand better)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11028/discussion-between-karlkoeller-and-andrea-l)

Comment: *A Graham's number of thanks*! At the end of 7 hours rebooting my system inside regedit, this issue has finally been solved. All I got to to was restore my OS from the "Backup" folder inside the Control Panel, then your code works perfectly.

Comment: @AndreaL. Really happy that, after a marathon, you've solved!

Comment: Yes, you can say that again. Now I'll need some sleep `:-)`.