# How to "cleanly" update TeXworks under MikTeX 2.9

Tags: installing, miktex, windows, texworks

A while ago I was struggling to obtain [TeXworks working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137452/texworks-wont-open-cls-extensions) correctly with MikTeX 2.9.4521-x64 under Windows 7-x64; and after a marathon I managed to correctly match the appropriate extensions with the registry (it seemed all was going to be fine).

But, looking up on the main site of the editor, I found that a new version was released, and since I like to have programs with recent fixes I decided to apply for an even *exchange*; i.e. *I wanted my TeXworks distribution simply and clearly replaced by the newest one inside the appropriate folder*.

The comment of @karlkoeller is a valid help to get my first step done; but I have still some worries about installing a new version.

*Where exactly has to be put in order to have the same folder structure as before?*

**Disclaimer:** The below statements are based on personal deductions, so they may be lacking of accuracy/preciseness.

With a little explaining, I learnt that not one folder of TeXworks is placed inside my OS; so the main distribution of this program (installed using MikTeX `setup.exe`), when removed, is called by the whatever-folders it may be stored in to be deleted (and the registry cleared).

*End of deductions.*

The main problem is that I do not know how this behaviour is like when I try to install a brand new/separated version of this program (I don't think that a reverse logic would apply). So what are the steps to follow?

Comment: Some advice: If I were you, Step 1: I would remove the TeXworks from MiKTeX `miktex-texworks` via "MiKTeX Package Manager" remove "miktex-texworks-bin-2.9" using `Administrator` privileges since it's not always uptodate with latest release. Step 2:If necessary use registry cleaner like http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner Step 3: Download and Install the [Stable TeXworks channel for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/downloads/list?can=3&q=OpSys%3DWindows) and also [keep miktex uptodate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast The procedure seems to be perfect; but (it has to be one of course...) will I be sure that every shortcut created with the *previous* version will be the same as the *newest* one?. One example would be checking TeXworks' `preferences and resources`, I think that the dir wouldn't be the same. Will this mis-match create problems?

Comment: I am not on windows ,no idea what you are talking but I know stable texworks from channel will work fine with miktex and integrates well similar to any external tex editors texmaker texstudio etc..

Comment: @texenthusiast Here is my simplified question. Whenever I remove a program (A), its installation directory should disappear, as well as the file extensions associated. When re-installed the program may have a different directory from the previous one. If another program (B) has "to know" if (A) is present, *would it search for (A) automatically into the new directory or not? Will this generate an error?* [(A) LaTeX IDE / (B) LaTeX Distro].

Comment: A and B communicate via Path of MikTeX bin and stable TeXworks installation directory set during their respective installations. Note: In Windows, sometimes it does not completely remove the installation folder and file associations (dependent on software uninstaller), henceforth ccleaner. But i doubt for texworks it is not needed, just makesure the miktex bin path set in windows `Path`. Check this by typing at commandline `pdflatex sample2e` to get a `sample2e.pdf` doc

Comment: If you are satisfied , I shall make my comments into answer to keep this away from unanswered list

Comment: @texenthusiast Mmh... After having tried the sequence suggested, just yesterday night I managed to have a new version of TeXworks with MikTeX, so that pretty much solved my issue (I needed to know the path set by windows, so testing `sample2e.pdf` gave me the folder `OS(C:)\Users\Andrea`. Now this is the directory where to install the new version.

Comment: Usually path in windows is set by miktex and texworks during their installation unless something bad happens. CD to DESKTOP and run the test (`pdflatex sample2e` will work from any where. Here is a link for how to set  [executable path in windows](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)).

Comment: @texenthusiast Just checked, and it shown the `...\MiKTeX\bin\x64` folder _as predicted_ (thanks). So now all I have to do is uninstall TeXworks, and when it comes to install a new version do I need simply to specify that the installation folder should be inside `C:\Program Files(x86)`?

Comment: Go with Defaults for TeXworks Stable installation from channel. TeXworks stable should integrate well with MiKTeX (atleast that was my past experience on windows)

Comment: @texenthusiast Yay! Following the defaults worked perfectly, now I don't even have two shortcuts to two different TeXworks distributions (thanks to reg.cleaner). Now that my issue has finally been solved, with all of this information, if you can squeeze them inside an answer I'll be honoured to accept it `:-)`

Comment: Great to hear it worked. Ok done. you can add anything if i missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following

**Step 1**:  Remove the `miktex-texworks` via "MiKTeX Package Manager" remove "miktex-texworks-bin-2.9" using `Administrator` privileges since it's not always up to date with latest release.

**Step 2**: In Windows, sometimes it does not completely remove the installation folder and file associations (dependent on software uninstaller), henceforth ccleaner. If necessary use [registry cleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner)

**Step 3**: Download and Install the [Stable TeXworks channel for Windows](https://github.com/texworks/) , Go with Defaults for TeXworks Stable installation from channel. TeXworks stable should integrate well with MiKTeX (at least that was my past experience on Windows) and also keep miktex up to date

**Step 4**: Finally, make sure the miktex bin path set in Windows Path. Usually path in Windows is set by `miktex` and `texworks` during their installation unless something bad happens. CD to DESKTOP and run the test `pdflatex sample2e` at command line prompt, it would work from any where if miktex path was set properly. Check this by typing at command line `pdflatex sample2e` to get a `sample2e.pdf`.  Here is a link for [how to set executable path in Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx).