# Generating file associations on Windows Part II: DVI

Tags: installing, miktex, windows, dvi

This is going to be a simple addendum to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137452/texworks-wont-open-cls-extensions) (detailed enough I think, with image proofs) on how to set properly file associations on my machine; `OS: Windows 7 64 bit Professional, LaTeX: MikTeX v2.94 x64 Updated October 2013`.

As a result, @karlkoeller gave an amazing solution, a re-implementation of all the connections between file extensions and programs inside a file `additions.reg`; this worked well to obtain a result with `*.tex`, `*.cls`, `*.bib` et similia.

The main request would be on *the last extension available, `*.dvi`*, i.e. having installed correctly YAP, I only need the specified association inside Windows Registry by another `additionsdvi.reg`, since the result at the moment is the same as my first question:

> [image]

As it can be seen, on the `File Type` it appears as `File DVI`, the same as `File CLS`. This is windows itself that does not have a clue on which program has to be assigned, as it did the last time with the `class` extension.

My experience is not enough to mess with this important stuff, as I learned it on my skin by "fighting" 7 hours straight as my PC slowly turning into complete chaos (I solved by a rough reboot, which I do not want it to repeat again).

Comment: Double clicking on the icon does anything?

Comment: @egreg The icon it's here only because I had to *manually* add YAP to a `*.dvi` file. If I hadn't done that, there would've been a blank icon with *no program associated*. Question edited to represent my initial condition.

Comment: What happened with the context menu and the option *Open with...*? When I used to use Win this options was there and you could associate a program to each file type.

Comment: @Sigur Surely I could have done this in the first place, but see, the difference between this method and the Registry implementation lies inside the *user specified file association*: if the user decides to assign by itself an extension opener program, then the file opens without problems; but the registry has *different* information (different icon set, minor changed options, backwards compatibility,...) than applying a direct `*.reg` file. It's like telling a machine to do automatic work instead a step-by-step human acting on the process.

Comment: @Sigur To be strict: *Yes*, I could have done that, but the minor changed options (icons, other evil stuff that may be affecting me on the future...). But instead I wanted that Windows would not ask me the association file program *in the first place*, since it's not already implemented inside the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following what you've done in the previous thread, now the contents of the file `additions.reg` has to be:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dvi]
@="MiKTeX.dvi.2.9"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9]
@="DVI File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\yap.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\yap.exe /dde"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\open\ddeexec]
@="[open(\"%1\")]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\print\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\yap.exe /ddenoshow"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\print\ddeexec]
@="[print(\"%1\")]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\printto]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\printto\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\yap.exe /ddenoshow"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MiKTeX.dvi.2.9\shell\printto\ddeexec]
@="[printto(\"%1\",\"%2\",\"%3\",\"%4\")]"
```

Comment: You definitely deserve a coffee... `=)`

Comment: @AndreaL. Troppo gentile...

Comment: In verità è gentile colui che dedica tempo a chiarimenti (almeno a me) essenziali.

Comment: @AndreaL. Coffee! not a beer? ;-)